Has there been any performance benchmarking of successive substitution vs. Newton-Raphson?
I've worked for two companies in chemical / energy industries.  In both cases, I've encountered internal software that uses successive substitution to solve nonlinear systems of equations representing some engineering problem.
The successive substitution algorithm is simple and requires no Jacobian.  I describe it below.  It seems to require that the equations can be re-arranged such that each variable appears alone on the left-hand side.
While "successive substitution" seems to be a common term in the industry, it is not described by my Numerical Methods textbooks, and literature searches don't turn up much material.
Textbooks like Numerical Recipes in C (Press et al.) and Numerical Methods for Chemical Engineering - Applications in MATLAB (Beers) instead describe methods like Newton-Raphson and Broyden's method for solving systems on nonlinear equations.
It raises a few questions.

Is there a more universal term for successive substitution that will turn up more literature?
Is successive substitution not described by textbooks because it is universally worse than Newton-Raphson?
Are there any references that benchmark successive substitution against Newton-Raphson?

    Pose equations so one variable is on the l.h.s.
    
    x1 = f(x2, x3)
    x2 = g(x1, x3)
    x3 = h(x2, x3)
    
    Start with guess for x1, x2, x3
    
    Evaluate the r.h.s. of each equation
    And use the solved l.h.s. for next iteration
    Iterate to convergence


For 1: Iterative methods is a more common name for this (or "relaxation methods" in numerical recipes IIRC)

The method you're describing is fixed-point iteration. The fixed-point method, if it converges, generally exhibits linear convergence, whereas Newton's method usually has quadratic convergence.

@Karl : That depends on how you count. One Newton step requires $(2n+1)$ function evaluations so that the order is $2^{1/(2n+1)}$ per function evaluation. If you add a simplified Newton step, this gives a composite order 3 for $2n+2$ function evaluations, giving a higher order $3^{1/(2n+2)}$. Note that the fixed point iteration has one function evaluation of the vector function per step.

Greatly appreciate the discussion.  Implementing Newton-Raphson on these problems would require a numerical estimation of the Jacobian by finite differencing.  Drastically increases the number of function evaluations.  Can we still expect improved performance in this scenario?

Do not forget that automatic differentiation of codes do exist. Have a look at https://www-sop.inria.fr/tropics/papers/supportCoursDA.pdf. So starting with the code of the function, you will have an automatic generation of the Jacobian and even the Hessain if required.

In linear systems, and sometimes also applied to non-linear systems it is called the Gauß-Seidel method. In the linear case it has slightly super-linear convergence.
As one can read in the literature about Gauß-Seidel, diagonal dominance is very important to get a convergent scheme. In more non-linear terms, the change in the isolated variable should be smaller than a Lipschitz constant times the change in the variables on the right side. Finding such an arrangement of the equations is a kind or art, there is no systematic way about it. In contrast to Newton-like and quasi-Newton methods, where preparatory system transformations can have an impact, but usually not a large one. Compare computing square roots starting from $f_1(x)=x^2-a$ and $f_2(x)=ax^{-2}-1$ as a trivial example.
With a reliable library for linear algebra, it is more efficient to implement a restarted simplified Newton method. That is, you obtain the Jacobian and its factorization and keep it for 10 or so Newton steps. Then compute again the Jacobian and so on.
